# Generators on a list vs chaining generators and memory consumption?

Tags: python, generator

Can anyone explain how generators work in these examples ?

In this example from http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/index.html

```
wwwlog = open("access-log")
bytecolumn = (line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in wwwlog)
bytes = (int(x) for x in bytecolumn if x != '-')
print "Total", sum(bytes)
```

1. When we chain generators like this does any real work happen other than code object creation until we do sum() ?
2. Why do we need to do line.split(None,1)[1]
   and int(x) separately - is there an advantage in doing that ?

In this example (x*x for x in range(1,100000000))

1. Is range(1,100000000) computed at all in Python 2 when this expression is evaluated by the interpreter ?
2. Does that happen during this statement or during the first run of the generator
3. Is this any different in Python 3 ?

*Reason* I had this doubt is this snippet:

```
def foo():
    for each in range(1,100000):
      yield each

a = foo()

# Here range is not evaluated until generator is run or just 
# before first yield is hit which is expected.

a=(x for x in range(1,100000)) 

# I thought also does exact thing as that function and it i is a 
# syntactic sugar for a=foo() which also yields a generator object.
```

Are there any advantages of using generators over list or scenarios where it is more practical to do that?

Comment: If its too broad , does this question belong to any of the sites in SO ?

Comment: I don't see why this is too broad - it has several well defined questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have done a few minor edits to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.When we chain generators like this does any real work happen until we do sum() ?

> Generator expression return an object that produces results on demand instead of building a
> result list so your answer is No (but it still depends on your mean about **real work**).

2.Why do we need to do `line.split(None,1)[1]` and `int(x)` separately - is there an advantage in doing that ?

> it just make your code more readable and increase flexibility (based on what you may do with that expression), you can do it in one line :

```
(int(line.rsplit(None,1)[1]) for line in wwwlog if ine.rsplit(None,1)[1] != '-')
```

In this example (x*x for x in range(1,100000000))

3.Is range(1,100000000) computed at all in Python 2 ?

> yes it dose , instead in python 2 you can use `xrange` that return an iterator.

4.If so is that during this statement or during the first run of the generator

> ...?

5.Is this different in Python 3 ?

> in python 3 meany of built-in functions return an iterator like `open` or `range`

For answer to your 4th question and your question in comment i think this part of [***learning python by Mark Lutz***](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) could be helpful :

## Generator Expressions: Iterators Meet Comprehensions

In all recent versions of Python, the notions of iterators and list comprehensions are
combined in a new feature of the language, generator expressions. Syntactically, gen-
erator expressions are just like normal list comprehensions, but they are enclosed in
parentheses instead of square brackets:

```
>>> [x ** 2 for x in range(4)]
[0, 1, 4, 9] # List comprehension: build a list
>>> (x ** 2 for x in range(4))
<generator object at 0x011DC648> # Generator expression: make an iterable
```

In fact, at least on a function basis, coding a list comprehension is essentially the same
as wrapping a generator expression in a list built-in call to force it to produce all its
results in a list at once:

```
>>> list(x ** 2 for x in range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

## List comprehension equivalence

Operationally, however, generator expressions are very different—instead of building
the result list in memory, they return a generator object, which in turn supports the
iteration protocol to yield one piece of the result list at a time in any iteration context:

```
>>> G = (x ** 2 for x in range(4))
>>> next(G)
0
>>> next(G)
1
>>> next(G)
4
>>> next(G)
9
>>> next(G)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...more text omitted...
StopIteration
```

We don’t typically see the next iterator machinery under the hood of a generator ex-
pression like this because for loops trigger it for us automatically:

```
>>> for num in (x ** 2 for x in range(4)):
...
print('%s, %s' % (num, num / 2.0))
...
0, 0.0
1, 0.5
4, 2.0
9, 4.5
```

As we’ve already learned, every iteration context does this, including the sum , map , and
sorted built-in functions; list comprehensions; and other iteration contexts we learned
about in Chapter 14, such as the any , all , and list built-in functions.
Notice that the parentheses are not required around a generator expression if they are
the sole item enclosed in other parentheses, like those of a function call. Extra paren-
theses are required, however, in the second call to sorted :

```
>>> sum(x ** 2 for x in range(4))
14
>>> sorted(x ** 2 for x in range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>> sorted((x ** 2 for x in range(4)), reverse=True)
[9, 4, 1, 0]
>>> import math
>>> list( map(math.sqrt, (x ** 2 for x in range(4))) )
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Generator expressions are primarily a memory-space optimization—they do not re-
quire the entire result list to be constructed all at once, as the square-bracketed list
comprehension does. They may also run slightly slower in practice, so they are probably
best used only for very large result sets. A more authoritative statement about per-
formance, though, will have to await the timing script we’ll code later in this chapter.

Comment: You real work happens if that answer to after sum() work happens before that just code object gets created ?

Comment: @Nishant exq ... can you explain more clearly ?

Comment: Until the python interpreter hits sum() hardly anything more than creating generator object (something has an ability to do something) happens? Virtually very few real work - correct? In this case the real work is reading the file in the first example. "When we chain generators like this does any real work happen until we do sum() ?" I asked any real work happens - so yes to real work happens or none happens ?  According to me none like @sweenerod said.

Comment: i thinks this question is a bit Specialty , as i mentioned in answer im not 100% sure , pls give me time for answer

Comment: what is the reson of down vote ? please let me and community to now the reason and correct it .

Comment: Please don't put words in other peoples mouths, it's extremely rude. I downvoted a previous incarnation of this answer because parts of it were wrong (still are). I've *kept* the downvote because to "fix" your mistakes you've just copied and pasted someone elses work into your answer. Please see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64627/245076) on quoting a book in an SO question. While you attribute the author (in all lowercase lettering in the middle of a sentence, so it doesn't exactly stand out!) I think this borders on the line of "Fair Use".

Comment: As per @ffisegydd's message, there are inaccuracies in your answer.  In fact, the very first point is wrong - "does any real work happen before sum()?" the answer is "No, because generators are lazily evaluated" rather than "Yes".  Your answer to point 2 is also wrong, because in your second code, you're doing the rsplit twice, one for generating the results, and again for the if-clause.  Generally, there seems to be confusion between iterators (objects that support the iterator protocol) and generators (objects that are iterators, w/ internal state that often means memory efficiency)

Comment: xrange adds to the confusion by returning an iterator that is almost a generator, but not quite, such as supporting multiple iteration passes through the same xrange object.  Sensibly discussing iterators, generators and xrange is really tough in my experience.

Comment: @zehnpaard about the first question its just a typo as i mentioned in answer *Generator expression return an object that produces results on demand instead of building a result list* so its very clearly that the answer is NO , and about the second how you say its wrong its just could be an inefficient way , not wrong (and its because of the possibility of performing that task)! any way thanks for your attention and reminding !

Comment: @Ffisegydd the reason of saying that comment is because of this post by you in chat room (`Maybe he should be sure before he answers a question :/`)and as i told you before you can tell your opinions by comment i think this is the purpose of the comment ! that improve the interactions of users . and you doesn't did that till now (although i mentioned in above comment that *what is the reson of down vote ? please let me and community to now the reason and correct it*). and now i'm grateful for your comment and telling me about **Fair Use** , i fixed the name of book authors too ! thanks again !

Comment: I've said my bit now Kasra, there are still issues with your post that you haven't bothered to tidy up so I'm not going to reverse my  downvote.

Comment: @Ffisegydd can i ask you pleas correct it for me ?

Comment: @Kasra, no. If I was going to do that I might as well write my own answer.

Comment: zehnpaard has already explained most of the problems anyway.

Answer (score 5):

1. Generators are lazy, so nothing happens until you iterate through them (e.g. with `sum`).
2. It just makes it more readable. You could write it like this if you wanted to:
   `bytes = (int(x) for x in (line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in wwwlog) if x != '-')`
3. Yes, in Python 2 `range` returns a list, you need `xrange` to produce a generator-like object.
4. It is calculated when the generator is iterated through, nothing is done until then.
5. Yes, in Python 3 `range` behaves like Python 2's `xrange`. The same thing happened to other functions like `map` and `filter`.

The main advantage generators have is that they don't store their entire contents at once. Their main disadvantage is that you can only iterate through them once.